# Can we ask the opinions of people in Meta about the scope of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, meta

I want to know what people here think about the type of questions that should be asked in SO, but a very specific aspect of this. The problem is that I don't know if such questions are OK in Meta. So, I must ask the question whether this kind of questions can be asked in Meta. Can I try to find out the opinions of others in Meta about some specific aspect of the scope of SO?

Let me give an idea of the specificity of the question, which I am not sure is OK in Meta. Most upvoted questions in SO are questions that arise while one writes code. But me I spent a lot of time reading code of popular framework and I  have questions about why they use this specific statement, etc. It's not at all the same kind of questions than those that arise when you write code.

I would like to ask what are the opinions here about this kind of questions, but I am not sure it is OK. Can we discuss that here in Meta?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's fine. You even did it correctly here: Ask a question on Meta about Meta and add the [meta](/questions/tagged/meta) tag.

Just ask a question such as "Is xxx on-topic here?" and add some relevant details.

Don't worry if people downvote you here, that's usually just an indication of disagreement (or saying "no", as opposed to "your question's crap" on Main).

As an example, say someone makes a feature request asking "should we add this to the site", and people don't like the idea. They downvote the feature request (which is a question) because they don't agree with it. Sometimes, people also downvote a question as a way of saying "no", e.g. "Is xxx on-topic here?" : "no".

As I've noticed, there are several layers of Meta-ness to your question. Typically it's not a great idea to ask a question like this: "Can I ask a question on Meta about whether something is on-topic?", because that's what Meta is for. Instead, just ask a question like this: "Is something on-topic?"

Comment: @Dominic108 Just ask about the main site. It gets confusing when you add several layers of Meta-ness to it. "Is it on-topic to ask about problems that arise when you try to understand code of popular frameworks?"

Comment: Yes, I realized that. I got confused in my previous comment, which I deleted. Of course, we have this extra layer of meta-ness here. There is no need to do it again. Yes, you phrased the question that I had in mind perfectly.

Comment: @Dominic108 Yes, but asking a question about asking a question on Meta is just several layers of confusing.

Comment: Well, it worked just fine apparently, here.